# Trying to init an expo app using npx create-expo-app in a directory other than the basic \Users\

Tags: npm, expo, npx

When I run npx create-expo-app in the default directory it creates the app just fine, but exists in my home which takes ages to transfer to the one I want it to be in. However when I run cd "G:\ .." and then run npx create-expo-app it has an issue with parsing an empty JSON string

I've tried reinstalling node and updating npm